# How to use Flex SOAP classes in Flash Pro

Tags: flash, apache-flex, soap

Is there a way to use the soap web service classes that FLEX provides from Flash CS5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here are some instructions](http://as3flashcs5.blogspot.com/2010/12/connect-flash-cs5-as3-with-web-service.html) from someone who did the same thing.

To quote some relevant passages:

First of all you need to link to the flex  webservices library from flash cs5 where you can find it in the below link :

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe
>   Flash Builder
>   4\sdks\4.1.0\frameworks\libs

in your flash document you need first to import web services namespaces :

```
import mx.rpc.soap.*;
import mx.rpc.events.*;
import mx.rpc.AbstractOperation;
```

then when you need to call the web service you need to initialize the object then load the WSDL call, after the event Load is trigger then you can call any method from this web service :

```
var uNameWebService:WebService;
var serviceOperation:AbstractOperation;
CallService_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, InitWebService);
function InitWebService(event:MouseEvent):void
{
Result_txt.text = "INIT"
uNameWebService = new WebService();
uNameWebService.loadWSDL("http://localhost:55166/Service1.asmx?WSDL");
uNameWebService.addEventListener(LoadEvent.LOAD, BuildServiceRequest);
}
function BuildServiceRequest(evt:LoadEvent)
{
Result_txt.text = "START"
serviceOperation = uNameWebService.getOperation("GetName");
serviceOperation.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, DisplayError);
serviceOperation.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, DisplayResult);
serviceOperation.send();
}
function DisplayError(evt:FaultEvent)
{
trace("error");
}
function DisplayResult(evt:ResultEvent)
{
var UserName:String = evt.result as String;
Result_txt.text = UserName;
}
```

Comment: Thnx! Do you have an example that passes parameters to the service?

Comment: I don't, no.  But, Google around I'm sure they are out there.

Comment: I find a lot but for mxml... I'll keep searching...thnx again

Comment: Second the call for parameter passing. I've been googling for ages.

Comment: Third the call for parameter passing.